# How many moves (shifts) are needed to sort an unsorted sequence of numbers $1$ to $n$ in ascending order?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have the LUP decomposition of a matrix. The determinant can be found from the formula:

$$\det(A) = \det(P^{-1}) \det(L) \det(U) = (-1)^s \left( \prod_{i=1}^n l_{ii} \right)  \left( \prod_{i=1}^n u_{ii} \right) $$

where $P$ is a [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) and $s$ is the number of row exchanges needed to transform $P$ into an identity matrix.

My question is how to find $s$ for a given permutation matrix? It's equal to the number of column(or row) exchanges when converting $P$ into identity matrix. (I'm writing a script for it, so the answer should be usable in a computer program)

This question is equivalent to *How many moves (exchanges of two numbers) are needed to sort an unsorted sequence of numbers $1$ to $n$ in ascending order?* Because if you write the 1s in the matrix as ordered pairs $(i,j)$, to come up with a identity matrix, these ordered pairs must be like $(i,i), (j,j),...$. We write pairs with the first elements sorted from $1$ to $n$, and then we sort the second elements, by exchanging two (second element) numbers at each move.

(for example, for $(1, 3, 4, 2)$, the number of moves is equal to $2$:
$$(1, 3, 4, 2)\to(1,2,4,3)\to(1,2,3,4)$$

)

Comment: What exactly is a *move*? Does moving an element past $n$ other elements count as $n$ moves, or as one?

Comment: @fgp It counts as one move. Each exchange of two numbers counts as one move.(it's equivalent to exchanging two columns of a matrix)

Comment: Thus the answer to @fgp's question is that it count as n moves.

Comment: sorting is done in $O(n\log{n})$, thus there is some constant factor and binary logarihm inside the formula...

Comment: Usually, you get the number of row exchanges AS you calculate the decomposition, not after... What context is this for?

Comment: @Alec I'm given the decomposition and I want to find the determinant from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear in using the word "move" since one cannot move one column without also moving some others to make place. In your example moving the final $2$ to position $2$ (and shifting the entries $3,4$ to make place) would sort your permutation at once. Since you count two moves nonetheless, you must be taking the interchange of two entries (or columns) as basic operation. This is called a transposition. Since the move can be realised by interchanging the "moving" entry $2$ succesively with the intermediate entries $4$ and $3$, I thought (before details of the intermedate steps were given) that you were counting swaps of *adjacent* numbers, which are called *simple* transpositions (as opposed to a general transposition which interchanges any pair of entries/columns; allowing those often allows to sort in fewer steps). As it turns out you allow general transpositions, so I'll discuss both cases separately.

Asking how many simple transpositions are needed to sort an array of length$~n$, is basically asking for the complexity ob bubble-sort in terms of the number of effective swaps needed. The answer is that this number is the number of inversions in the original sequence, which can be at most $\binom n2=\frac12n^2-\frac12n$ (if the input was sorted in the opposite direction). Taking a random input, the number of inversions is symmetrically distributed between that maximum and the minimum $0$, so the average value is half the worst case value.

Allowing for arbitrary transpositions, the minimum number of swaps necessary is $n-c$ where $c$ is the number of orbits the permutation gives on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ (these are the cycles in the cycle decomposition of the permutation, but with the convention that every fixed point counts for a separate cycle). One clearly has $0<c\leq n$, so at most $n-1$ general transpositions are necessary to sort an arbitrary array of length $n$. The distribution of the value of$~c$ is not symmetric, and for large $n$ it is likely to be quite small; see [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) for detials.

Given a permutation you can find the minimum number of swaps in $O(n)$ time, essentially by tracing out the orbits it defines. While the value $v$ of the first element is not $1$, swap it to its final position $v$ (eventually the element at position $v$ that it swaps with will be the element $1$, and one can then stop; this corresponds to closing of the cycle in the original permutation that contained the initial element). Doing so, mark the set of positions that are thus already known to be in their final state. After this first obit is done, search for the next non-marked element, and repeat; and so on until everyone is marked.

This does not contradict the known fact that $\Omega(n\lg n)$ comparisons are needed to sort arbitrary array of length $n$, because in a permutation we know up front that the entry $i$ will end up in position $i$ after sorting, whereas in general arrays one has no such knowledge. I'm not sure whether there is a sorting algorithm of a *general* array (not necessarily a permutation) that both achieves the absolute minimum number of swaps and that runs in $O(n\lg n)$ time overall.

Comment: I mean general transposition too. Because *that* determines the number $s$ in the expression for the determinant. I also expanded the example at the end of the question (Sorry if my wording was not clear).

Comment: @user215721: Then the example at the end is badly chosen, as it already can be sorted with $2$ _simple_ transpositions. However sorting $(3,2,1)$ can be done in $1$ transposition (of the outer elements), but requires $3$ simple transpositions. Anyway I've addressed the general transposition case as well now.